# About GetTempPath function in Win32 API

Tags: winapi

Why does [GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992(VS.85).aspx) always return short path names? Is there a way to return the long path name rather than subsequently converting the returned string with [GetLongPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992(VS.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetTempPath` is most likely returning the value of the `TMP` or `TEMP` environment variables, which (at least under Windows XP) are typically defined in terms of the short path name.

Windows appears to convert to the short path name from the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` registry key when initializing environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use GetTempPath, why not just get the value of the TEMP environment variable?  That will be the long path already.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that this is done for compatibility reasons. 
In older Windows versions temp path was relatively short. In latest Windows this path is much longer. Many old application may use a buffer of fixed length (small length) for retrieving temp path. 
If you return long file name (which is relatively large now) - you'll broke this old programs, because their buffers just too small for it to fit. That's why GetTempPath returns short path name.